# How to elegantly sum into repeated indices of a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I am trying to figure out a way to do the following without a loop:

Lets say I have a vector `x` where I sum some elements `e` into. I also have a vector of indices `ids` which say to which elements of `x` to send the values to. i.e.

```
x = zeros(1,4);
e = [ 1 10 100 1e3 1e4];
ids = [1 1 2 4 3];
```

I would like to do something like

```
x(ids) = x(ids) + e
```

That will return

```
x =

          11         100       10000        1000
```

because we refer to x(1) twice, while instead it returns

```
x =

          10         100       10000        1000
```

Comment: Use `accumarray` : `accumarray(ids,e)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`accumaray` is a really useful function for doing such tricks. In your case:

```
accumarray(ids',e)
```

will do the job.

Comment: Like @Divakar mentioned in [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405192/how-to-elegantly-sum-into-repeated-indices-of-a-vector-in-matlab#comment56552235_34405192) indeed. What's up with the transpose? There's no need for that.

Comment: @Adriaan I think it would be needed with `ids`, when it is a row vector. So, to make it generic to make it work with any vector, one could do `accumarray(ids(:),e)`. The transpose on `e` isn't needed though.

Comment: OP has ids as a row vector and accumarray will interpret that as one index of a 5 dimensional vector. Transposing the e was not required, that's my mistake.